# In TypeScript, how can you extract a class instance type using generics?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, mapped-types, inferred-type

Poked around SO looking for an answer for this but turned up dry – in my GraphQL server, I'm trying to add better typing around my subscriptions because the types I pulled from NPM use `any` too much. I wrote a map outlining my subscriptions, where each map value contains the channel name, subscription name, and an object class that is used to type the payload:

```js
class ConversationCreatedEvent {
  conversationID: string;
  userID: string;
}

export const Subscriptions = {
  conversationCreated: {
    name: 'onConversationCreated',
    event: ConversationCreatedEvent,
    channelName: 'CONVERSATION_CREATED',
  },
};
```

I'd like to write a method that allows you to publish subscriptions that takes two arguments: the subscription ID (map key), and an object conforming to an instance of class type specified in the `event` field.

So far, I have:

```js
const publishSubscription = <T extends keyof typeof Subscriptions>(
  name: T,
  data: typeof Subscriptions[T]['event']
) => {
 // TODO: implement
};
```

However, this approach makes the second argument `typeof ConversationCreatedEvent`, and expects keys such as `length`, `name`, `apply`, etc. (i.e. the keys you'd find in a class object, not an instance of the class). I need this to accept the actual class members, such as `conversationID`.

Hope this all makes sense. I feel like it's very straightforward, there's just something small I'm missing. I'm still learning mapped types.

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const Subscriptions` has the class constructor as a value. So:

```
typeof Subscriptions['consoversationCreated']['event']
```

is the same as:

```
typeof ConversationCreatedEvent
```

Which means that you have a class constructor type, and you want to get the instance type from it.

Typescript has a built in utility type to do just that [called `InstanceType`.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype)

```
class Foo {}

// The following type aliases are equivalent
type FooInstance = Foo
type InstanceTypeFoo = InstanceType<typeof Foo>
```

Or in your case:

```
InstanceType<typeof Subscriptions[T]['event']>
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=9&pln=16&pc=55#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2A7AbgUwE4TAFwJZNnVR1QBMBRNRbaAbwChppgk1Md9EBJAEQC5oEbOlyIA5tAC80AOQyA3I2gBXCBl4ChI8VNkL6AX3r0WiIdADKygEYRgIgA54kMaQyam2WZ4kLFsZALuTNCIYAC2qAIyBKwY3px+JKQyADRKTKhU2AIIKPEcBETJlKjU6SHMABZgiIioIAByEVGysADyjQBq5ABKFgCCACpcnQD6sL3kw+Q8aUoG6QaKJi40DjYguBBVVrb2uE6cugA8Q9CoAB4BiKQwANaoAJ7wAGbQ2E8OqG+WNnaOHwQAB8AAolGFIgIhhVoKQcGABFwzNhasBUEMvqgTp9vr89gDDkCANpDAC6xJkWTK2BkZOB9AAlFJgXRGAB6dnQIbtHjtAS4cIOECoSLUQwrDbWLY7AkHI5IUEyTwFHxJAIpVJ0Zhxdg+DSyACMACYAMxpFRqdAGmRgazAGTQAyMoA)

Comment: WOW I had no idea! That works perfectly. Thank you!